# How to communicate between fragment that holds the viewpager and viewpager's fragments (MVP)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, mvp

I'm building a mvp application and i'm looking for a clean and correct way to communicate between **main fragment** and those **viewpager's fragments**.

More specific,I have :

- JobsFragment : fragment which contains the view pager
- NewJobsFragment : one of view pager fragments
- RecommendedJobsFragment : 2rd fragment from viewpager
- SavedJobsFragment : 3rd fragment from viewpager

All viewpager's fragments contain a RecyclerView.Each part uses a MVP structure ( *JobsFragment* has it's own *JobsPresenter*,*NewJobsFragments* has *NewJobsPresenter* and so on)

User can filter the jobs in each fragment.Those filters can be selected from *JobsFragment* and when this is happening I need to 'notify' current fragment from viewpager and send those filters to it.

I read about child-parent relationship between presenters but I don't think it's a proper solution.
I also think about sharing a single presenter for all fragments but it's a lot of code and I guess it won't be readable anymore.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can do it using JobsFragment `Instance` and other Fragments `getter` method .

Comment: Use polymorphism with a base abstract Fragment _or_ EventBus mechanisms _or_ ViewModel from Android Architecture Components _or_ share your presenter if you got one for the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create one Abstract Fragment that extends Fragment. like this

```
   public abstract BaseChildFragment extends Fragment{ 
      public void onViewPagerPagechange(); 

}
```

Make All ChildFragment (JobsFragment , NewJobsFragment  etc) extends BaseChildFragment ,
On your Pager Adapter add below code.

```
LruCache<Integer,BaseChildFragment> cache = new LruCache<>(4);
public BaseChildFragment getBaseChildFragment(int position){
   return cache.get(position);
}

 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == JOB) {
        if (Utility.isEmpty(fragmentProfile)) {
            jobsFragment = JobsFragment .getInstance()
            cache.put(position,fragmentProfile );
        }
        return jobsFragment ;
    } else if (position == NEW_JOB) {
      ......
        return fragment;
    }
    return null;
}
```

On your Fragment that has View pager AddpageChangeListener like this

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

// optional 
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

// optional 
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
 BaseChildFragment fragment =   adapter.getBaseChildFragment(position);
fragmeng.onViewPagerPagechange(); 
//you can invoke presenter logic by calling this method on each child presenter will call your filter (its upto you)
 }
    // optional 
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }

});
```

This will call your ChildFragment `onViewPagerPagechange();` method. where you can load your child fragments. you can also get currently selected fragment. and simplest way is that you can get current fragment and check with `getInstance();`